# How can i create a online catch tool which can capture part of a web page?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I saw this demo: [Capture demo](http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120720jsoupjquerysnatchpage/index.html), it looks it use jsoup to capture the web element. Do we have any other choice for capture the web page content better? FOR example, capture the part of web page, and also include js, so it can function correctly just like original page. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: I see a lot of cross-origin issues here...

Comment: Do you mean screenshot capture?